# How to count thread running per second in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I am so much confused with Jmeter test configuration. I found lots of answers but non those clear my doubt. My thread group contain 10 threads and all are in active state. I want to hit 20 requests per second to server. Load need to last for 60 seconds.

I put

thread count : 20
Ramp Up Period : 1
Loop Count: 60

Is it correct method to hit 20 requests/second last for 60 seconds?

Answer (score 0):

For Request Per Second we should not calculate manually, instead leave the headache to JMeter. Just make sure, to have enough Threads to reach that TPS and JMeter will control the pacing. If the Threads are less and Request Per Second is more, than JMeter cant to anything and RPS wont be met.

Use Throughput Shaping Timer to achieve Request Per Second [Throughput Shaping Timer](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ThroughputShapingTimer/)

**How Many Threads I Need To Produce Desired RPS?**
Threads pool size can be calculated like `RPS * <max response time> / 1000`. The more rate desired the more threads you will need. The more response time service have the more threads you will need.

For example, if your service response time may be 2.5sec and target rps is 1230, you have to have `1230 * 2500 / 1000 = 3075` threads.

It is better to have some threads overhead to handle unexpected response time spikes. But beware of too much overhead, it will lead to "final spike".

Use Following settings in Thread Group and Throughput Shaping Timer:
**Increase Number of Threads if 20 TPS is not met.**

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use stepping thread group or concurrency thread group instead of basic thread group to achieve your desired results.

https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ConcurrencyThreadGroup/

[image: Stepping Thread Group]

Comment: How does this answer the question of achieving 20 RPS or N RPS?

Comment: Just check the x-axis and y-axis to get the understanding.

Comment: This will only controls the Threads, RPS will be much more than 20 if server returns response less than a second. Nowhere will it control the RPS.

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration will be correct only if:

1. You have only one [Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers)
2. It's response time is **equal** to 1 second

Correct configuration would be something like:

[image]

The best approach would be going for [Concurrency Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ConcurrencyThreadGroup/) and [Throughput Shaping Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-throughput-shaping-timer-plugin/) combination. They can be connected together via [Feedback Function](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ConcurrencyThreadGroup/#Use-With-Throughput-Shaping-Timer-Feedback-Function) allowing the Concurrency Thread Group to kick off more threads if current amount is not enough to conduct the required load.